# PHP What browser the user is using?

Tags: php, http, browser-detection

This is my current code, but I get a parse error when I run it? Have I just made a silly error or will this not work? Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
browser();
function browser() {
    $browsers = array('chrome', 'msie', 'firefox', 'safari');
    for ($i = 0; $i < $browsers.length + 1; $i++) {
        if (SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == $browsers[$i]) {
            echo "You are using {$browsers[$i]}.";
        }
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `SERVER` should be `$_SERVER`; if there are other parse errors, it would really help if you included them in the question.

Comment: `SERVER` should be `$_SERVER`.

Comment: Don't reinvent wheels: [`get_browser()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) PHP often has built-ins for common web-like stuff :)

Comment: In addition to the addition of the above comments, you could do a string match (regular expression), or even `strpos`. @andrewsi You're too quick! Beat me by 4 seconds :P

Comment: Question: why not just  `echo "You are using {$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']}.";`?  Looping through the array seems excessive.  EDIT: Or I've been beaten to suggesting that by three other users.  Impressive.

Comment: You should probably try var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); to see what that super global actually holds.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code.  First `$browsers.length` is not the way that value is calculated in PHP.  It seems like `.length` is a JavaScript format?  It should be `count($browsers)`.  Also, you have `SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` when it should be `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. I also changed your `echo` format so it’s more readable. This should work without failing completely:

```
browser();
function browser() {
    $browsers = array('chrome', 'msie', 'firefox', 'safari');
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($browsers) + 1; $i++) {
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == $browsers[$i]) {
            echo "You are using " . $browsers[$i] . ".";
        }
    }
}
```

But if I were you I would approach your logic as so using [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/in_array) instead of a `for` loop:

```
browser();
function browser() {
    $browsers = array('chrome', 'msie', 'firefox', 'safari');
    if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $browsers) {
        echo "You are using " . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . ".";
    }
}
```

Basically that `for` loop is excessive for the logic presented. Just use `in_array` to check of the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` is actually in `$browsers`.

That said, browser detection is not as simple as your overall logic implies.  But this at least solves your most immediate PHP problems at gives you something to build on.

Comment: `$i < count($browsers) + 1` should be `$i < count($browsers)`. Also, as none of the strings in $browsers match any user agent string, there will never be any output from this.

Comment: I think that is splitting hairs. The function still fails in that it doesn't do what it is supposed to do, it just doesn't fail visibly any more. Well, it does actually it raises "Notice: Undefined offset: 4" because you have that +1 in there.